# Centre Button text

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a user control with some Buttons. Each Button contains text which I'm struggling to align/centre within the control.

The XAML I have is

```
<UserControl x:Class="ProjectX.DetailedInfo"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="28" d:DesignWidth="575">
    <Grid Height="28" Width="575">
        <Button Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="525,2,0,0" Name="buttonOP1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="46" Click="buttonOP1_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="11" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

But the text is not aligning properly, see below

[image]

`HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"` and `VerticalContentAlignment="Center"` doesn't seem to be working as expected. Does anyone know why?

(I've checked the text and there's no extra characters)

Thank you

Comment: Ideally it should work, check if space is not trailing your content

Comment: Are you setting the text using the "Content" parameter? Are you using a simple string, or putting your own xaml into the content i.e. a textblock?

Comment: Where/how're u setting the `content` parameter?

Comment: In code using `buttonOP1.Content = dataReturned1.ToString().Trim();` - Just a thought, does trim only remove spaces or ALL whitespace?

Comment: can you do buttonOP1.Content=`string.Format("[{0}]",dataReturned1.ToString().Trim());` This will wrap the string in [] allowing you to see if there is extra spacing in the content.

Comment: Sorry everyone - false alarm - there is a newline added after Trim further in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button content is by default centered in WPF. I would assume that for the buttons that have mis-aligned captions, the text contains spaces after the actual number. But it's hard to tell without you posting all relevant code.